# How to get measure value for certain date range in MDX?

Tags: ssas, mdx, date-range, mdx-query

I am new to MDX and for now it looks like some hell to me.

I have a measure called `Sales KG`. It calculate sales amount based on table `AData` where I have column named `Data_Date`.

I need to get `Sales KG` value for specified range of dates.

The problem is I can't understand how to specify that range. It doesn't look like simple `<` and `>` are works here.

I totally lost and don't have much to show, but this is what I tried:

```
select
[Sales KG] on Columns
from [Model]
where ([Format_TT].[Супермаркет], [Data_Date].&[20160101] : [Data_Date].&[20170101])
```

But it tells me that can't convert string "20160101" into date type. And probably this is not what I want. I want it to be single value for date range in single cell.

What to do?..

Comment: Do you have a dimension Data_Date in your cube, based on your question you are saying that Data_date is a column in your fact. It will not help if it is not a dimesnion in your Cube. MDX will only be able you access your cube's dimension and measures not the underlying star schema.  You need to check what is the datedimension in your cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the below sample they will help .

Please note that "Date" is a dimesnion in the cube, which has an attribute "[Date]" in it. "[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]" in the cube. It is necessary to have them defined in the SSAS project, If one of them is not defined in the project but exists in the base tables of star schema it will not work. MDX can only see objects defined in the SSAS project

//First way

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns
from [Adventure Works]
where {[Date].[Date].&[20130101]:[Date].[Date].&[20130131]}
```

[image]

Second way

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
{[Date].[Date].&[20130101]:[Date].[Date].&[20130131]}
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The first way is what I need. I will try to get same results and understand what you saying about SSAS thing.

Comment: @Kosmos you are welcome. What i was saying is the base tables are not exposed in your SSAS or cube. So MDX cannot access them. MDX can only refernece object defined in SSAS project or cube.